# How to create a curved line at a specific place in CSS 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, border

I have a navigation bar at the top of my site with my logo. How to create a curved line under the logo ?

I wish the line to be continuous and face just a small curve under the logo. Is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS:

```
`.rounded_underline{
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}`
```

or you could add an HTML SVG tag:

```
<svg>
    <circle  stroke-width="3" stroke= "blue" fill = "none" cx="50%" cy="-80" r="130"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tested but I did not manage to do as in the capture. Here is the address of my site, this is the navigation bar at the top https://www.s1biose.com

Comment: I can't see the site because it's in maintenance mode. I put the examples in a pen, so you can see them and play with them. **SVG**: https://codepen.io/Dashiee/pen/djjdmp **CSS**: https://codepen.io/Dashiee/pen/pZOaeL

Answer (score 0):

This shadow is tricky, but you could use pseudo elements and do something like this (pay attention to z-indexes)
https://codepen.io/kali187/pen/zyPaGg

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

  header::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  header::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 12rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }
  

header h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 auyto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>icon</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: If you need anything more smooth at connections between the circle and the rectangle, then svg and curves